# Where are my email replies to sellers located in my Amazon account?

Tags: amazon

I emailed a seller several questions about an item from one of the accounts a week or two ago.

How do I see a receipt for that email (a copy of what I wrote) and how do I find the place where the replies would be?  Am I to assume that it will ONLY go to my email addresses on file and not show up in my account?

Answer (score 2):

all should be in **Message Center**

- click on “Accounts & Lists”
- go to YOUR ACCOUNT ( See Link )

`https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/homepage.html/ref=nav_youraccount_ya`

- at the bottom it says “Message Center”